# AWK - Match Field1, Exclude Last Field, Print Line if Fields in Between Mismatch

Tags: awk

I have two files.  I want to compare the two files and use field1 for matching.  I want to exclude the last field for comparison.  If all fields in between do not match, then print both lines and return. Lines can have a different number of fields in between the first and the last.

**File1**

```
LSP0    NODE0   NODE4   NODE3   591
LSP1    NODE1   NODE2   NODE3   725
LSP2    NODE4   NODE5   515
LSP3    NODE2   NODE4   NODE3   NODE6   725
```

**File2**

```
LSP0    NODE0   NODE4   NODE5   NODE3   515
LSP1    NODE1   NODE2   NODE3   576
LSP2    NODE4   NODE5   615
LSP3    NODE2   NODE1   614
```

**Output**

```
LSP0    NODE0   NODE4   NODE3   591
LSP0    NODE0   NODE4   NODE5   NODE3   515

LSP3    NODE2   NODE4   NODE3   NODE6   725
LSP3    NODE2   NODE1   614
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ 
         rec1 = $0; $NF = ""; trimmed = $0; getline < "file2"; rec2 = $0; $NF = ""; 
         print ($0 != trimmed? rec1 ORS rec2 : "")
     }' file1
```

The output:

```
LSP0    NODE0   NODE4   NODE3   591
LSP0    NODE0   NODE4   NODE5   NODE3   515


LSP3    NODE2   NODE4   NODE3   NODE6   725
LSP3    NODE2   NODE1   614
```